# Get size of icons on desktop in OSX using Cocoa or Applescript

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, applescript

Is there any way to get the size of the icons on the desktop in Cocoa or Applescript? Preferably in cocoa.

Comment: Take a look at http://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=19001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use applescript to get it this way:

```
set icon_size to word 3 of (do shell script "defaults read com.apple.finder DesktopViewSettings | grep iconSize")
```

You could do in Cocoa a similar way using a shell call.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apple script

```
tell application "Finder"
    set p to get the properties of icon view options of the window of the desktop
    set iconSize to icon size of p
end tell
```